# Fancybox: iframe doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Very simple test.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /* This is basic - uses default settings */

            $("a.iframe").fancybox();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="iframe" href="http://www.google.be/">This goes to iframe</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Yet, fancybox just won't work... The references to the js file and css are correct. JQuery functions normally. But clicking the link acts just a normal link. Ie: I get redirect to google.be. FYI: It's not just with google, it's with every single URL I put there. What am I missing here?

Comment: Stupid question, but it looks like you copied and pasted from the tutorial. So, do you actually have the js and css files locally?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought!

Comment: @bobthyasian yes I do :) I copied from the tutorial because that was the most basic example that should work. All the references to the files are indeed correct.

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Console says nothing I'm afraid... It just goes to google without throwing any errors ors warnings.

Comment: Have you tried to calling the script after the `anchor`? Like imjared's code.

Comment: Just tried that, same result.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had success changing the *class* on the anchor to `fancybox fancybox.iframe`.

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.google.be/">This goes to iframe</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('a.fancybox').fancybox();

    });
</script>
```

No idea why this is the case but it worked for me.

**Edit**: also need to update to a recent version of jQuery

Comment: Odd, from the docs:

Script uses the `href` or `data-fancybox-href` attribute of the matched elements to obtain the location of the content and to figure out content type you want to display. You can specify type directly by adding classname (fancybox.image, fancybox.iframe, etc) or `data-fancybox-type` attribute. Use `title` or `data-fancybox-title` attribute to specify item caption.

Comment: here's a jsfiddle where you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/rJndu/3/embedded/result/

Comment: I found out there was hidden character somewhere causing shenanigans, but still: It doesn't work with me... Literally copied your code, dubblechecked all the references, displayed an alert as a test that the jscript is executing. Firebug doesn't throw any errors either. Everything seems OK, yet the link keeps acting like a regular link instead of opening an iframe..

Comment: Your best bet here then might be to download the example, change the link, then just reduce the case down while making sure it works. Can you confirm that my example works for you at the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Yes, your jsfiddle works fine. I just tried to make a new, empty project with 1 html file, 1 js file and 1 css file. The contents are exactly like your jsfiddle. Still doesn't work :p

Comment: Are you still using jquery 1.4? When I use that version, it doesn't work. When I use recent (1.8) it works.

Comment: Ok, very odd :D That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Just as an explanation because @imjared said :

> No idea why this is the case but it worked for me.

Since you are trying to open an external page, the logical step is to open fancybox in `iframe` mode, however fancybox has no means to know that it has to wrap the content in an `iframe` tag.

There are three ways to tell fancybox to do it :

1). Add `type: "iframe"` to your custom script like :

```
$('a.fancybox').fancybox({
   type: "iframe"
});
```

2). Add the attribute `data-fancybox-type="iframe"` to your `<a>` anchor tag like :

```
<a class="iframe" href="http://www.google.be/" data-fancybox-type="iframe">This goes to iframe</a>
```

It requires HTML5 `DOCTYPE` though.

3). Add the special class `fancybox.iframe` to your `<a>` anchor tag as in the accepted answer.

The fancybox script is able to evaluate any of the states above but you should choose at least one of them to make it work (you could use more than one or altogether and it will work, but it's redundant)

**NOTE** : this is valid for fancybox v2.x+ only (... and requires jQuery v1.6 or later)

BTW : Due to security restrictions, some websites cannot be opened in an `iframe`, like *google* or *facebook* for instance. You should always consider the **[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)** working with iframes and ajax content.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me thanks to @JFK instructions:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

    <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
            type: "iframe"
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" data-fancybox-type="iframe">This goes to iframe</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like cross-domain links are not opening. 
I was using localhost, and using `href="http://localhost/example/?page_id=7896"` only works. If i write `href="http://google.com"` it doesn't works. In case you can check by putting your site on a domain and use `href="http://example.com?page_id=7896"`

In html:

```
<a id="iframe" href="http://localhost/example/?page_id=7896">Link</a>
```

in js:

```
$("#iframe").fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe'
});
```