# Fancybox to open a text file?

Tags: jquery, file, text, fancybox

I wanted to make a website where i can preview with FancyBox files of some kind of types, like for example, images, text documents, etc.

Doing this:

```
$(".text").fancybox();

<a class="text" href="document.css" title="document.css"><img src="files.png"/>OPEN ME</a>
```

It opens the Document but it doesnt respect the margins and format of the document, i mean, everything is written in the same line, cause i suppose it opens it as if it would be an HTML, not as an Text Editor.

So does anybody how to open it in the way Notepad++ or GEdit, for example, opens it?

Thanks!

Comment: please add it to jsfiddle.net, and show more details

Comment: You would need to pass the document to open as a parameter to a parent page which gets the file and formats it using a plugin, such as SyntaxHiglighter: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/. Opening a text file in a browser will result in an unreadable mess.

Comment: Okay, i've just realized that if you add to the fancybox for the class 'text' the propierty 'type: iframe' it works properly.
$(".text").fancybox({
'type'    : 'iframe'
                        });

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh, i've checked that url and okay, i think it could be very useful to include it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most text files, you may need to open them using an `iframe` so you can keep the format, then your link should look like :

```
<a class="text fancybox.iframe" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css">open css file</a>
```

... notice the special class `fancybox.iframe`. Then your code as simple as :

```
$(".text").fancybox();​
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nQrZp/)**

For more about how to select fancybox `type` of content, check :https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869696/1055987