# fancybox open inline content but not iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

this is working fine

```
        function openContent (id) {
            $.fancybox('<h1>Lorem lipsum</h1>');
        }
```

but when I try to open an iframe, nothing happens

```
        function openContent (id) {
            $.fancybox.open({href:'http://www.google.com'});
        }
```

no error message in firebug or chrome console.
i'm trying in localhost.

any idea?

Comment: If you want to open an iframe you have to tell fancybox the type of content. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13869696/1055987 for further reference and explanation

Comment: you may also want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14828632/1055987 regarding some iframe issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
 X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

header is set in www.google.com, you cannot open www.google.com in iframe if your site is not in google.com.

Comment: thanks, google was just a susggestion. i'm trying the same with a file in same folder "iframe.html" and not works too

Comment: As per this link http://fancybox.net/blog try  $.fancybox({href:'http://www.example.com'});