# JQuery FancyBox With IFrame Issue (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

Hi I am trying to use FancyBox in a page I am making containing videos, Like a Gallery of videos, my intention is to be linking YouTube videos in.

The issue I get is it just links through to the age link a normal `a` tag would do and nothing else happens.

This is the code I am using to generate the videos.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         echo "
             <div class='portalVideo'>
                  <a class='fancybox fancybox.iframe' href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DB7jsjt4Uec'>
                      <h3>
                          <strong>".$row["VideoName"]."</strong>
                      </h3>
                  </a>
             </div>";
    }
```

All my video link are pulled from a database and then displayed on the page as a a text link which "should" open the `iframe` when clicked. The only aspect that doesn't work is the `iframe`. everything else pulls and displays correctly.

I have included the files correctly and they link correctly to the resources. just for consolidation see below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css">
```

Based off [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868132/fancybox-iframe-doesnt-work)  I have tried to fix it. My code does contain the jquery below just under the head tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two (none PHP related) issues :

1). This *youtube* format :

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DB7jsjt4Uec
```

.... is not supported inside an `iframe` because most likely it contains a `DENY` [`X-Frame-options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) response header. You may need to convert it into an *embed* format like :

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/DB7jsjt4Uec
```

2). The special class `fancybox.iframe` is only supported in fancybox **v2.x** but you seem to be using fancybox **v1.3.x**. So you rather use the *class* `iframe` or add the API option

```
type: "iframe"
```

... to your custom fancybox initialization script.

Since you are pulling the video links from a database, the good news is you don't have to change anything in your PHP code but only in your jQuery code like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").each(function (i) {
        // change links on the fly to embed format
        this.href = this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'embed/') + "?autoplay=1";
    }).fancybox({
        // API options
        type: "iframe" // needed for videos embed format
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** I am adding `?autoplay=1` to the new `href` but that's optional if you want your videos `autoplay` once in fancybox's `iframe`.

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**