# Fancybox youtube callbacks not working

Tags: jquery, youtube, callback, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using the following code to open a youtube video in fancybox.

```
$("#videos a.fancybox").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'         : 1280,
        'height'        : 720,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
            'wmode'             : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

However I'd like for it to do something before the window appears. I'll include it below.

```
$("#videos a.fancybox").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'         : 1280,
        'height'        : 720,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
            'wmode'             : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            var id = this.element.attr("id");
            alert(id);               
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Basically it grabs what's in the ID and attempts to alert it. With this piece of code, the window won't open and will redirect to youtube. If I put something like `alert("ohi");` it'll display correctly, but I have to delete the var. Does anybody have any idea why? If I include it in another fancybox code, it works, like:

```
$('#photos a.fancybox').fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    beforeShow: function () {
        var id = this.element.attr("id");
        alert(id);               
    }
});
```

Why isn't it working with the videos?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of fancybox?

Comment: Hi there. It's 2.1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you to forget about the `.click()` method and use the fancybox media helper.

```
<script src="{your path}/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

Then bind your selector in the normal way to fancybox.

Here is your tweaked code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#videos a.fancybox").fancybox({
        padding: 0,
        // autoScale: false, // not a valid v2.x option
        // transitionIn: 'none', // not a valid v2.x option
        // transitionOut: 'none', // not a valid v2.x option
        // title: this.title, // not needed or it should be inside a callback
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        fitToView: false, // to respect the fixed dimensions above (optional)
        helpers: {
            media: true // enable fancybox media helper
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            var id = this.element.attr("id");
            alert(id);
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

**NOTE**: it's assumed that the selector with *class* `.fancybox` also has an `ID` attribute, otherwise it will return `undefined`

---

P.S. If you don't want to use the media helpers, you could change the `href` on-the-fly to youtube's `embed` format and set fancbox `type` to `iframe`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462518/1055987 for more

Comment: For some reason this is working in the fiddle but not in my localhost :\ just freshly downloaded the media js, it is correctly called and even put the code in a fresh new correctly called js file. Tha heck?

Comment: For some reason it's not going through the script when clicking on `a`. EDIT: I have this error in the console `TypeError: F is undefined fancybox-media.js (line 89, col 1)`