# Fancybox set content source class name

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Using FancyBox 2, I've only been able to trigger content source types via a class on the triggering element. As an example, `<a href="..." class="fancybox.iframe">...</a>` will trigger an iframe.

I'm actually updating from fancybox v1 on an existing code base, and adding these classes to each link isn't particularly desired.

I can:

- Add this class dynamically with JS (each link has a class of `iframe` for jquery to hook onto, I could simply add the right class on top of that on page load)
- Somehow change the settings of fancybox 2 to pickup the `iframe` class and use that instead of `fancybox.iframe`.
- Add `type: iframe` to the call options.

For the sake of compatability, I'd really like to go with the second option, but there's nothing on their documentation on whether it's possible.

Is it possible to change the class fancybox looks for to detect the content source?

Comment: are you sure this is correct ? AFAIK, dot character is, among other characters, not a valid character in class names, cause this would obviously make selectors ambiguous.

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples, under the "Various Types" tab. You can see in the HTML that the ajax link uses the `fancybox.ajax` class, while the iframe links use `fancybox.iframe`.Their JavaScript is a blanket hook for all links (not specifying the type via JS)

Comment: What I see there is exactly what I was about to advise, a data-attribute. Here it is for the iframe : `data-fancybox-type="iframe"`. I'm quite sure this is what is used to bind JS events, and this could explain why it doesn't work when you try. CSS classes ideally shouldn't be used as data or configuration storage...

Comment: It's possible and completely safe to use the second option as you want to. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13869696/1055987 for more